# I deleted some photo from my Lumia930 but they still in onedrive

Tags: sync, onedrive, photos

I deleted some photos from my Lumia930 but they still in OneDrive. How can I sync it properly?

Comment: What do you mean by "sync it properly"? Do you want the photo back on the phone, or delete them from OneDrive?

Answer (score 1):

Photo upload for OneDrive is a one-way sync only. If you want to delete images both on your phone and on your OneDrive you'll have to do that manually.